# Most efficient singleton pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

I am reading about singletons, and don't understand why this

```
public class BillPughSingleton {
    private BillPughSingleton(){}

    private static class SingletonHelper{
        private static final BillPughSingleton INSTANCE = new BillPughSingleton();
    }

    public static BillPughSingleton getInstance(){
        return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

is more efficient than this

```
public static ThreadSafeSingleton getInstanceUsingDoubleLocking(){
    if(instance == null){
        synchronized (ThreadSafeSingleton.class) {
            if(instance == null){
                instance = new ThreadSafeSingleton();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `volatile` if you use double-checked locking. As of java 1.5 double-checked locking works with `volatile`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first pattern saves you the hassle and performance "overhead" of checking for `null`s - the classloader should assure that the class is loaded and initialized only once.

Comment: what about the getInstance method? Can that be non-static?

Comment: @user3289157 it has to be `static`. Since you shouldn't be able to create a instance from outside the class (the constructor is private), this would be the only way to get an (the!) instance  of the class.

Comment: what does it mean to make a function static though? Can there be more than one "instance" of a single function at once?